# wget has no file permission

Tags: permissions, wget

Ubuntu 14.04

I can not use wget and I'm using the root account:

```
wget whatever
/usr/bin/wget: Permission denied

ls -ld /usr/bin/*

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       23632 Feb 11  2015 /usr/bin/watch
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       39648 Mar 11  2016 /usr/bin/wc
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       75944 Apr 28  2014 /usr/bin/webapp-container
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root      231592 Apr 28  2014 /usr/bin/webbrowser-app
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root         286 Dec  8 00:37 /usr/bin/wftopfa
---------- 1 root root      407696 Jun 14  2016 /usr/bin/wget
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       48112 Sep 24  2014 /usr/bin/whatis
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       15128 Nov 24 06:25 /usr/bin/whereis
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root          10 Nov 26  2015 /usr/bin/which -> /bin/which
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       51968 Mar 11  2016 /usr/bin/who
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       27200 Mar 11  2016 /usr/bin/whoami
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root       53048 Aug 25 01:43 /usr/bin/whoopsie
```

I can not chmod it:

```
chmod 755 /usr/bin/wget
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/bin/wget’: Operation not permitted
```

What should I do? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First do `sudo chattr -i /usr/bin/wget` and then `sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/wget`.

The `-i` flag sets the file as immutable, giving it the following characheristics:

- A file with the i attribute cannot be modified.
- It cannot be deleted or renamed, no link can be created to this file
  and no data can be written to the file.
- When set, prevents, even the superuser, from erasing or changing the
  contents of the file.

Comment: same output still: sudo chmod 755 /usr/bin/wget
chmod: changing permissions of ‘/usr/bin/wget’: Operation not permitted

Comment: what does `sudo lsattr /usr/bin/wget` show?
what does `sudo ls -lah /usr` show?

Comment: `sudo lsattr /usr/bin/wget` `----i--------e-- /usr/bin/wget` `sudo ls -lah /usr` `total 156K` `drwxr-xr-x  10 root root 4.0K Apr 17  2014 .` `drwxr-xr-x  23 root root 4.0K Feb  3 00:13 ..` `drwxr-xr-x   4 root root  68K Feb  3 01:21 bin` `drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4.0K Dec  6 18:30 games` `drwxr-xr-x  39 root root  20K Dec  6 18:28 include` `drwxr-xr-x 159 root root  20K Feb  3 00:51 lib`